# How to add Func<T, string> of constrained Ts to a collection using that constrained type

Tags: c#, generics, collections, casting, expression

I'm trying to create a list of Functions but I'm struggling.  Here is a simplified version:

```
public class ValueGetter
{
    public List<Func<Control, string>> Operations { get; set; }

    public ValueGetter()
    {
        this.Operations = new List<Func<Control, string>>();
    }

    public void Map<T>(Func<T, string> valueGetter) where T : Control
    {
        this.Operations.Add(valueGetter);
    }        
}
```

The issue comes when I try to add the function to the collection.  I would have through I'd be able to do this as T is a control however this doesn't compile.

Is there a way I can add the function to this collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible.

Although `T` is a `Control`, not all `Control`s are `T`s.
What happens if you add a `Func<TextBox, bool>` to the list, then call it (as a `Func<Control, string>`) with a `Button`?

You can use [covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) to cast a `Func<Control, string>` to a `Func<T, string> where T : Control>`, because any possible `T` is also a `Control`.

Comment: Thank you, I was forgetting the Func may not work on other types of controls.

Comment: @Liath: really what you need here is the constraint "where Control : T", that is, where T is Control or any base type of control. Then it would be type safe. Unfortunately, C# does not support this kind of constraint. Try Scala if you're looking for a language that can express that sort of constraint; I think they can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud declare the class as generic:

```
public class ValueGetter<T> where T : Control
{
    public List<Func<T, string>> Operations { get; set; }

    public ValueGetter()
    {
        this.Operations = new List<Func<T, string>>();
    }

    public void Map(Func<T, string> valueGetter)
    {
        this.Operations.Add(valueGetter);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn’t work, because you would end up having, for example, a `Func<Button, string>` in your list, but you could end up calling it with, say, a `Label`. What is the function, which expects a `Button`, expected to do with a `Label`?

You could do something like this:

```
public class ValueGetter<T> where T : Control
{
    public List<Func<T, string>> Operations { get; set; }

    public ValueGetter()
    {
        this.Operations = new List<Func<T, string>>();
    }

    public void Map(Func<T, string> valueGetter)
    {
        this.Operations.Add(valueGetter);
    }
}
```

In other words, have separate `ValueGetter`s for each Control type.

**Edit: Another idea:** You could add a function that simply allows the operation only if the type is right, for example:

```
public void Map<T>(Func<T, string> valueGetter) where T : Control
{
    this.Operations.Add(control => (control is T) ? valueGetter((T) control) : null);
}
```

In this case, if the `Button`-expecting function is given a `Label`, it would simply return null.